# Where do the source files under /obj-c/target/enunciate/gen/ come from?

Tags: objective-c, maven, enunciate

I've been working with enunciate on my Mac. Since installing the latest version of the Xcode Command Line Tools, I get compiler errors on `enunciate.m` and `enunciate-common.m`. They're pretty basic syntax errors that I was able to solve easily by going into the `/obj-c/target/enunciate/gen/obj-c/` directory and editing the offending files. So, that's not my question.

The problem is, every time I run a `mvn clean install`, the changes I made are thrown away. So, I'd like to find out how the `enunciate.m` and `enunciate-common.m` files are being generated, so I can fix the problems at the source. I tried to figure it out on my own, but to no avail. I'm not too experienced with Maven, so I assume I'm missing something obvious -- like are the `.m` files being pulled from a repository elsewhere when Maven performs the `compile` stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enunciate uses [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) to generate all its code. The freemarker template you're interested in is [`api.fmt`](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/blob/master/obj-c/src/main/resources/org/codehaus/enunciate/modules/objc/api.fmt?source=cc) which ends up calling (among other things) [`common.fmt`](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/blob/master/obj-c/src/main/resources/org/codehaus/enunciate/modules/objc/common.fmt) and [`client-enum-type.fmt`](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/blob/master/obj-c/src/main/resources/org/codehaus/enunciate/modules/objc/client-enum-type.fmt) where your particular compile-time problems are being generated.